# Keep only those columns in dataframe based on min value of each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a datafrme

```
In = pd.DataFrame([["W",13,23,45,65], ["X",23,45,12,78], ["Y",12,34,56,89]],columns=["A","B","C","D","E"])
```

W row has min value 13, X row has min value 12, and Y row has min value 12. Keep only those columns that have min value of all the rows.

Expected output:

```
Out = pd.DataFrame([["W",13,45], ["X",23,12], ["Y",12,56]],columns=["A","B","D"])
```

How to do it?

Comment: What if you have two columns with the same smallest value in a row? Do you want to keep both or any?

Comment: Yes need to keep both columns

Comment: You may want to add this detail to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if a column is either non-numeric or contains the min.

This approach is efficient as it first computes the `min` per column, then compares each min to the global min.

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

# non-numeric
mask = In.apply(is_numeric_dtype)
# contains min
m = (m:=In.min()).eq(m[mask].min()) | ~mask
# If python < 3.8:
# m = In.min()
# m = m.eq(m[mask].min()) | ~mask

Out = In.loc[:,m]
```

Output:

```
   A   B   D
0  W  13  45
1  X  23  12
2  Y  12  56
```

Answer (score 2):

Very straightforward: declare 'A' the row index; find the column of the smallest element in each row; eliminate the duplicate columns; select the surviving columns and 'A' from the original dataframe.

```
columns_to_keep = In.set_index('A').idxmin(axis=1).unique().tolist()
Out = In[['A'] + columns_to_keep]
```

Note that if more than one column contains the smallest element in a row, only the first column is included in the answer.

Comment: While clever, this approach is incorrect. I would fail to identify a column if the min is only present in the same row as a previous column (`idxmin` only returns the first match), example invert 12 and 56 in column D

Comment: @mozway In your example, column B has all the minima and will be correctly selected. It is not clear from the question what to do if there is more than one minimum. Also, your solution works only in Python >= 3.8.

Comment: I provided an example in my previous comment: invert 12 and 56 in column D, D will fail to be selected

Comment: @mozway Check my updated comment.

Comment: I hope OP will clarify, but the way is phrased I'm pretty sure D should be selected. Regarding the assignment expression, this is an implementation detail, I added a note ;)

Answer (score 2):

Find min value amongst min values for each column. Equate outcome to df. Filter any columns with min value. Set A as index before filter happens

```
In.set_index('A', inplace=True)
In.loc[:,(In==In.min().min()).any()].reset_index()
```

Or the following if you do not want multiple lines of code

```
In.set_index('A').loc[:,(In==(In.select_dtypes(exclude='object').min().min())).any()].reset_index()
```

Comment: Nice, I used a similar approach but I think more efficient as it doesn't need to check all elements against the min, and is more generic (no need to set_index) ;)